# Extension that requires jquery v2 in yii2 that has jquery v3

Tags: jquery, yii2

I'm working in Yii2 and have jQuery 3. I've installed an extension that requires jQuery 2.

1. How can I connect jQuery 2 just for [this extension](https://github.com/vova07/yii2-imperavi-widget/issues/129#issuecomment-376094737)?
2. How can I make changes in my `AppAsset` for changing jQuery? My `AppAsset` at the moment:

```java
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css', // my css
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/site.js', // my js
        'js/jquery-2.2.2.min.js // LIBRARY THAT require WIDGET
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset', // jquery for yii2
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset', // js, css, jquery for bootstrap
    ];
}
```

Or how to make changes on config:

```
'assetManager' => [
    'bundles' => [
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
            'sourcePath' => null, 
            'basePath' => '@webroot',
            'baseUrl' => '@web',
            'js' => [
                'jquery-2.2.2.min.js',
            ]
        ],
    ],
],
```

Comment: jQuery v3 is largely backward compatible with v2. Is there a specific JS error you're receiving that is causing you to attempt this?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes:
table.js:267 Uncaught TypeError: $table.size is not a function

Comment: where are you using the redactor editor is it a single view where you need it ?

Comment: No, is a redactor text, that is used for a lot of views.

Comment: I need answer just for 1 question:
How can I connect jQuery 2 just for this extension?
Because for second question i found answer:
(1). Create a new layout
(2). For new layout connect jquery2
(3). And for views where is used jquery2 conect new layout.

Or another way, to change jquery for all aplication throught config/web.php